# Groovy remove multiline comment

Tags: regex, groovy, comments, multiline, replaceall

How do I remove a multiline comment using groovy?

```
/* Use groovy replaceAll regex to 
   remove this comment */
```

I read-in the above text from a file, to a file object, and then I convert it into a string. And if the comment spans a single line, I can remove it using the replaceAll method as posted below:

```
def file = new File('myfile')
def fileString = file.getText()

println fileString.replaceAll('/\\* .* \\*/','')
```

I have tried to use the (?m) flag, but I can't get it to recognize my pattern. I have tried the following statements and they all fail to match my pattern.

```
fileString.replaceAll('(?m)/\\* (.*) \\*/'    ,'')  #multiline switch
fileString.replaceAll('(/\\*)(.|\n\r)*(\\*/)' ,'')  #match all .* (include \n\r)
```

I thought about using the DotAll, the (\s) at the end, and ${}. But, I am not sure how to effectively mix it into the regular expression. Any help would be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
'(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/'
```

`(?m)` doesn't make `.` match new lines, `(?s)` does that.

Comment: It removes the content, but it leaves an empty line. I would like to completely remove the multiline comment from the file. Thanks.

Comment: so just add a newline in the expression: `'(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Does something like

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

work for the regex portion?

(From http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)

Comment: That's the *nedit* version; you don't need the `|[\r\n]` parts in Java/Groovy.  In fact, there are very few flavors in which a negated character class *doesn't* match newlines.  The article is somewhat misleading on that point.

Comment: No, I tried it just now and the interpreter reports an error on the 1st backslash (the 2nd character):

fileString = fileString.replaceAll('/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/','')

Comment: @tfmontague, you need to escape some of those backslashes like you did in your question.  Specifically, `\*` should be `\\*`.